# Angular 4 - Keep Nav Bar Around on Refresh

Tags: angular

I'm using an eventEmitter to display a NavComponent when a user is logged in. If I refresh the screen the NavComponent html disappears; presumably because the value I used to show/hide the header is no longer around after the refresh.

What's a good way to accomplish keeping something like `[hidden]="!loggedIn"` to stay `true` on a page refresh?

Here's some code:

LogInService contains: `@Output()
  userLoggedIn: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();`

My LoginComponent does this:
`this.managerService.userLoggedIn.emit(true);`

And then my NavComponent has this:

```
@Input()
    loggedIn: boolean;

    constructor(private service: LogInService ) {
        service.userLoggedIn.subscribe(loggedIn => this.loggedIn = loggedIn);
    }
```

So LoginComponent emits to LogInService and then NavComponent listens to LogInService as to whether `[hidden]` is true or false.

Comment: The application needs to store the loggedIn information (or, typically, a token identifying the current user) in a persistent location: a cookie, or local storage. Data stored in memory don't survive to a refresh.

Comment: don't you mean [class.hidden]="!loggedIn" ? and loggedIn is not an input in this case...

Comment: @andrea06590 I didn't realize there was any other way. The element with `[hidden]` on it is just a nav bar div. I'll take a look at what you mentioned.

Comment: @Justin class hidden is a syntax similar to ngIf but using the class template :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to accomplish this to use localstorage. You just have to make sure in the loginservice about the user already logged in, eg.:

```
private logInUser(user: User) {
    localStorage.setItem("userDetails", JSON.stringify(user));
    //nextValue here for the observers
}
```

And in your ngOnInit method you can check the localstorage and trigger nextValue if the user already logged in.

That's it!

Comment: I used both the emit event and the localStorage for login and logout duties. Anything other than localStorage to other people's point was lost regardless of where I tried to put it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in your LogInService class:

```
export class LogInService {
   isAuthenticated = false;

   identify(): Promise<boolean> {
      // retrieve your authentication HTTP API
      this.isAuthenticated = true;  
   }

   isAuthenticated() {
     return this.isAuthenticated;
   }
}
```

put your LogInService into your root level NgModule would make it **singleton**, you can access it anywhere of your project.

In your component:

```
isAuthenticated() {
    return this.logInService.isAuthenticated;
}
```

In template:

```
[hidden]="!isAuthenticated()"
```